# hover effect on another class in css

Tags: css

I have menu which the active item  has an active class on load, which changes its background.

The hover of other items change the background of hovered item.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<style>
  li:hover, li.active {background:black}
</style>
```

Is there any way to remove active class background on other items hover in pure CSS. something like:

```
li.hover .active {background:none}
```

This works if active is under li, but doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't reliably possible with CSS, as CSS can only affect elements that appear *later* in the DOM, not previously, so hovering over the *first* `li` can affect the current `li.active` element with the following CSS:

```
li:hover ~ li.active {
    background-color: #f00; /* or whatever */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNmPA/).

But hovering over the third `li` *cannot* affect the same `li.active` element.

However, the following would work:

```
ul:hover li.active {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNmPA/1/).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! And thank *you* for the accept! =)

Comment: You'r welcome. I just built the menu which used a lot of js with total css. This is great ;)

Comment: There may, though, be a slight problem for any users that insist on, or otherwise have to continue, using IE 6; as that browser only accepts `:hover` on `a` elements. Otherwise, though, it should be peachy.

Comment: As this is a proprietary application, I force users to use chrome or firefox! ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas - IE6 also wouldn't accept several other parts of the CSS in this answer! Good thing the world is finally getting the message about dropping it. (I note the number of IE6 tagged questions here has dropped substantially in the last few months)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul:not(:hover)>li.active { background: black; }
ul>li.active:not(:hover) { background: none; }
```

This has a few conditions:

1. A browser which supports the `:not` pseudo-tag
2. The `ul` must not have too much padding or empty space, otherwise you could activate the `:hover` of the `ul` without hovering over any `li`s

Comment: This remove background of active class when hover is on itself, I want to remove it when hover is on other items.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me :

```css
.dvchange1 {
  color:#fff;
    }
    .dvOne:hover .dvchange2 {
        color:#000;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="dvchange1 dvchange2">
    <span class="">
    Hello
    <span>
    </div>
```