# CSS Transition confusion when transitioning an element inside of its parent

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Given the following HTML and CSS:

**transitions2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS Transformations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="transitions2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**transitons2.css**

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 850px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #4682B4;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.wrap:hover .box{
  background: #F08080;
  margin-left: 75%;
}
```

My issue is with the last declaration selecting .box in .wrap:hover. How does this work? Why isn't .wrap moved as well? When I mouse into .box's parent element, only the .box is moved. What causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the parent doesn't move is because you are in fact *not* selecting it. Your code selects a child class of `wrap` named `box` when the hover event fires and makes its changes to that element.

If you want the parent to move instead of the child, removing the selection for the child class `box` is necessary, but will produce ugly results. The code above is working as expected.

Incidentally, the code can also be written as:

```
.wrap:hover > .box 
{
    background: #F08080;
    margin-left: 75%;
}
```

Which in my opinion makes it clearer to see what's going on, but that's my preference.

Answer (score 1):

`.wrap:hover .box` is just like saying

When I hover over `.wrap`, `.box` will do the following.

I actually find `.wrap:hover > .box a bit less obvious, but that's just me.

There is also [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603980/hover-effect-on-another-class-in-css)  - Different Example which also works.

```
ul:not(:hover)>li.active { background: black; }
ul>li.active:not(:hover) { background: none; }
This has a few conditions:

A browser which supports the :not pseudo-tag
The ul must not have too much padding or empty space, otherwise you could activate the :hover of the ul without hovering over any list.
```