# Sliding menu tab

Tags: javascript, css, joomla2.5

I've got a request of a client to make the menu tab slide whenever someone hovers over the menu tabs.

As for now I've got a li.active roll and a li:hover roll.

I don't know how to define a roll that upon hovering a non active menu tab the active one will change styling accordingly.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Slide how, where? Perhaps you could show us the current HTML & CSS and make a JSFiddle at the same time.

Comment: The example posted here is very close only that I need one hover effect which slides and not tow as demonstrated. See my comment to the other answer.

Comment: I've found this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603980/hover-effect-on-another-class-in-css which is what I need but it didn't work for me. Tried this: #sp-main-menu ul.level-0 > li:hover >a #sp-main-menu ul.level-0 > li.active >a {
    background: transparent !important;
 }

Answer (score 0):

something like this? @theguy

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Option1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
  <li class="slider"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Verdana;
  background-color: #eee;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #222;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  z-index: 7;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
}
a.active {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  pointer-events: none;
}
li.slider {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  z-index: 8;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  transition: left 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}
.menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(1):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(1):active ~ .slider {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(2):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(2):active ~ .slider {
  left: 25%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.menu li:nth-child(3):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(3):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(3):active ~ .slider {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}
.menu li:nth-child(4):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(4):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(4):active ~ .slider {
  left: 75%;
  background-color: #16a085;
}
```

Here you are the JSfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/Ugyh8/

Comment: Thanks allot. This is very close to what I need. The only thing is that the client asked for the whole box to move. In this demo the tab slides over but the active item is still marked. So you get two hover boxes. I need to have only ONE which slides on hover.

Comment: What I actually need to know is how to remove the li.active tab styling when hovering above other li tabs?

Comment: I feel I'm close but just not there yet. Tried this but it didn't work as well: #sp-main-menu ul.level-0 > li:hover #sp-main-menu ul.level-0 > li.active {
    background: transparent !important;
}

Comment: Can you add your jsfiddle? @theguy

Comment: Hi, it's a paid template and the menu CSS is scattered between several CSS files. Copying all this to JSFiddle will take me day :( I've got the site live at www.rom.guywalderonline.com there you can see the menu and inspect the elements. Will be grateful if you could help me solve this...